Screencapture + compression while recording
Is there an open-source, free tool that captures screen + audio but compresses it as it records it?
I have used macOS' default tool "Screenshot" (using CMD+SHIFT+5) but just a minute of recording takes about 800mb. One can encode it to another format that reduces the size substantially but I want to avoid out-of-space disk errors while recording.
